# Probability of the Number of the Draw = Probability of the Number of the Ball?

Tags: probability

I have a problem:

> If you have 10 balls labeled from 1 to 10, is the probability that the number of the draw matches the number of the ball $$1 - d(10)/10!$$ where $d(10)$ is the number of derangements of 10 balls?

Answer (score 2):

This would be the probability that at least one ball number matches the order of the draw.  The number of derangements is given in [A000166](http://oeis.org/A000166)  It is approximately $\frac{10!}{e}$

Comment: So it would be $(9/10)(8/9)(7/8) \cdots (1/2)$?

Comment: @Tony: no - because the number of derangements of 10 is 1334961, not 9!.